# $_session variable

Tags: php

I want to store some information like user_name, country_name etc and need to be available through out the session.

1. what will be the best way to achieve this?
2. I have the following code to `$_session` variable but have no result.

**page1.php**

```
 session_start;
 $_SESSION['country_no']=1;
```

**page2.php**

```
session_start;
echo "here is session variable=".$_SESSION['country_no'];
exit;
```

Comment: session_start is a function. So use it like a function!

Comment: @CanVural is totally right : use session_start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put session_start(); add the top of you page.

Answer (score 3):

`session_start()` is a function, use it like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['country_no']=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `()`

```
session_start();
```

Comment: I have the following error: 'Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\index.php:11) in C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12'

Comment: the session_start(); is between <head> </head> tags.

Comment: `session_start()` must be before any content, this beans before any character is printed, like `<html>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start(); //needed before you create any session variables.
$_SESSION['mysessionvariablename'] = $myVar;
```

Read up on the [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

try session_start(); instead of session_start;
You're using a method :)