# Add variable in session variable in PHP?

Tags: php, session, variables, cookies

How do I add a variable into `$_SESSION`?

```
$product = 0;
$_SESSION['product_number'.$product.''] = true;
```

It is not working.

Comment: You should read [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) if you are just getting started.

Comment: 1. Get rid of the `.''`, it is useless. 2. Are you calling `session_start()` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: "Is not working." Is not a valid error message.

Comment: Give more information; what do you mean by 'is not working'?

Comment: agree with @sammitch, you need to call session_start() at the top of your script if you want to use session variables at all.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704382/session-variable

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure you used [session_start()](http://www.php.net/session_start);

### page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$product = 0;
$_SESSION['product_number'.$product] = true;

?>
```

### page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$product = 0;
if ($_SESSION['product_number'.$product]) echo 'Session variable was set!';
else echo 'It was not!';
?>
```

Comment: @MattiRauhiainen Make sure to mark this answer as "accepted" if it is what you where looking for. Green tick = accept.

Answer (score 5):

This may work for you:

```
<?
session_start();
$product = 0;
$_SESSION['product_number'] = $product;
?>
```