# How to store session in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create  session in header.php but when I change my page session get destroyed automatically .

#### session start this code i have place at very top of header.php

```
session_start();
```

#### php code for session

```
<?php $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['herbew'];
if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){  
echo $_SESSION['lang'];   } ?>
```

#### HTML where I give option to user to change language

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="get">
<div class="lang">
<span class="english"><input type="hidden" name="english" value="english">
<input type="submit" name="submitsd" value="eng" ></span>
<span class="herbew"><input type="hidden" name="herbew" value="herbew">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="her" ></span>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: You need `session_start()` at the top of each page script before you can access or set the session data

Comment: See I use wordpress theme header.php file and I sure that each time header is call for other page . I say work but when I change the page it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

A session must be started inorder to access the session variables.

At the top of the page add:

```
session_start();
```

This will start a session. it's also required to have `session_start();` on every page that uses the session array.

---

If you are looking to add data to the session array. You will need to do this after user presses the submit button. Ie,

Form > Redirects to AddSess.php > Adds required values to session > Redirects to the correct page

Ie:

```
<form action="AddSess.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and on *AddSess.php*

```
session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $_SESSION[] = $_POST['test'];
  header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

*The above is a very basic example on how to append data to a session*

[Add variable in session variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203358/add-variable-in-session-variable-in-php)

Comment: Hope you have already wordpress knowledge. I have use this code in theme header.php file .When i submit button it work fine for me but WHEN I CHANGE PAGE OR REDIRECT TO OTHER PAGE headrer.php file remain same on each page so session should not be destroyed and secondly i did not have any need to call session.

Comment: As I said. Its a very basic example

Comment: [link](http://www.smartzonewebservices.com/dev/wc)

Comment: please check [link](http://www.smartzonewebservices.com/dev/wc)

Comment: For PHP to register that a session value has been added/changed/deleted it requires a refresh so PHP can read the most up to date session array. If you wish to go another option, Ajax might suit your requirements

Comment: I create a session why it should not save my data till I close browser  or destroy session.what reason i got this problem ?

Comment: @user3781881 As I said, without any form of Ajax/Javascript you will require a refresh of the page before changes are made fully visible

Comment: Hope you are right but I don not get user answer clearly

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your session variable everytime the page is called. if `$_GET['herbew']` is empty, so will be `$_SESSION['lang']`

Check `$_GET` before you assign it:

```
if (isset($_GET['herbew'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['herbew'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {  
    echo $_SESSION['lang'];
}
```